# Submission of Rails Jquery Modal form with validations not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

3 concurrent issues:

- modal form inline validations aren't showing up
- modal form isn't submitting
- where to define changes to page that occur after ajax
  submission? UJS file, jquery in js root, etc..

For context, here's the flow:

1. Non-user clicks "buy" button
2. 'transactions/form' modal form opens: contains a form that creates a new transaction and optionally- a new user (registration)
3. form contains stripe credit card fields and optional password/email fields, also contains hidden fields for information about the post (id, price, etc...)
4. User has two options:
   **a.** enter only credit details
   **b.** enter credit details and password/email, i.e. register
5. click submit
6. IF: option a, only credit details have been entered

   - validate card
   - charge credit card
   - close modal and make appropriate changes to the page
7. IF: option b, credit card + registration details have been entered

   - validate card and user details
   - create user
   - create customer and charge customer
   - close modal and make appropriate changes to the page
8. the post is changed from 'active' to 'inactive'

I'm using the client_side_validations gem.

In rough order of the steps above, here are the details for my buy button, modal form, jquery, and controller.

**View: post item with buy button and modal form:**

```
/button that opens modal form
%a.btn.buy-button{remote: :true,"data-toggle" => "modal", :href => "#buy_modal", :role => "button"} Buy

/the modal form
%div#buy_modal.modal{:role => "dialog",:style=>"display:none"}
  =render :partial => 'transactions/form'
```

**The Modal Form:**

```
  =form_for @transaction, :validate => true, :html => {:class => "form"} do |f|
    =yield(:user_validators)
    - if @user.errors.any?
      #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this group from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

    /POST DETAILS
    = f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token
    = f.hidden_field :price
    = f.hidden_field :tier_id
    = f.hidden_field :premium
    = f.hidden_field :notify_premium
    = f.hidden_field :user_id
    = f.hidden_field :customer_id
    /CREDIT CARD STUFF
    #credit-card{:style => @user.stripe_customer_id ? "display:none" : "display:block"}
      #credit-card-errors{:style => "display:none"}
        #stripe-error-message.alert-message.block-message.error
    %div.row-fluid
      = label_tag :credit_card_number
      = text_field_tag :credit_card_number, params[:credit_card_number], :class=>"credit-number span12"
    %div.row-fluid
      %div.span6
        = label_tag :expiry_date
        = date_select "", :expiry_date, {:discard_day => true, :order => [:month, :year], :use_month_numbers => true, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => Date.today.year + 25}, {:class =>"credit-expiry inline"}
      %div.span3
      %div.span3.credit-cvv
        = label_tag :cvv, "CVV"
        = text_field_tag :cvv, params[:cvv], :class=>"credit-cvv input-block-level"

    /NEW USER STUFF
    =f.label :email
    =f.text_field :email
    =f.label :password
    =text_field_tag :password, params[:password]

    =f.submit "Save"
```

**Jquery that manages the modal:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $buy_dialog = $('#buy_modal').dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false, 
    title: 'Edit',
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    buttons: {
                "Save": function() {
                        $("#new_transaction").submit(function(){
                            var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
                            $.ajax({
                                url: $(this).attr('action'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
                                data: valuesToSubmit,
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType: "JSON" // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
                            }).success(function(json){
                                //act on result.
                            });
                            return false;
                        });
                        $('#buy_modal').dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }

    });
```

**Jquery that manages modal inline validations**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form').enableClientSideValidations();
    $('.form').on('shown', function() {
      $(ClientSideValidations.selectors.forms).validate();
    });
};
```

**Transaction controller, `create` action:**

```
  def create
    @transaction = Transaction.new(params[:transaction])
    @user = User.new(:email => params[:transaction][:email], :password => params[:password])

    respond_to do |format|
      if params[:password]
        #let's make a user and a transaction object
        if @transaction.save
          @user.save_with_payment
          format.html { redirect_to @transaction, notice: 'Transaction was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @transaction, status: :created, location: @transaction }
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      else
        if @transaction.save
          @transaction.payment(params[:transaction][:tier_id],params[:transaction][:price],params[:transaction][:premium],params[:transaction][:premium_notify])
          format.html { redirect_to @transaction, notice: 'Transaction was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @transaction, status: :created, location: @transaction }
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

**User Controller, `create` action:**

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format|

      #OPTION A, explained above
      if params[:user][:password].nil?
        # Charge the card and don't make a user
        # get the credit card details submitted by the form
        token = params[:stripeToken]

        # create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
          :amount => 1000, # amount in cents, again
          :currency => "usd",
          :card => token,
          :description => params[:email]
        )

      #OPTION B, explained above
      else
        # create user, customer, and charge them
        token = params[:stripeToken]
        if @user.save_with_payment(token)
          @user.payment()
          format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
        else
          #error message
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

I realize this is a sprawling question, but this is a very common project element. I've trawled through stack overflow to find answers to each component, and nothing fits the bill.

[Submit Form in Rails in a ajax way with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723334/submit-form-in-rails-3-in-a-ajax-way-with-jquery)

[Jquery modal windows and edit object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766055/jquery-modal-windows-and-edit-object)

[Jquery modal box form validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638539/jquery-modal-box-form-validation) (tries to reinvent the wheel, not rails, and guidance is not canonical)

[Problems validating form input in a modal window with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439672/problems-validating-form-input-in-a-modal-window-with-jquery) (no MVC here and question isn't actually answered)

[client_side_validations gem with formtastic in jquery modal view not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135148/client-side-validations-gem-with-formtastic-in-jquery-modal-view-not-working) (not answered)

Answer (score 2):

partial answer :

#### modal form inline validations aren't showing up

Can't help you on this one

#### modal form isn't submitting

- rails has baked-in CSRF protection. Chances are that your request gets kicked out because you don't pass the required CSRF token
- you should add `remote: true` to your form options. It will let the unobtrusive rails driver manage the request for you (no need for form serialization), and trigger custom events depending on the response. See [Rails 3 remote links and forms](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/) or simply the [Rails AJAX guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html) for more info

#### where to define changes to page that occur after ajax submission? UJS file, jquery in js root, etc..

you can respond with js.erb files, same as html.erb files, with jQuery logic inside that will get executed in client context.

i tried to answer this more in detail, but your logic is very byzantine (and i think you lost some statements  in option A during copy/paste, because there is no save / format for this option). As a side note, this kind of case would be make a Data-Context-Interaction architecture relevant.

Comment: oops... i hit save by mistake. to be continued

Comment: no worries. My logic is definitely convoluted. Let me post some edits to clarify

Comment: added transaction controller- which is actually being called by the modal